# Persisting batch entities are taking long time to save into DB : Hibernate : JPA

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm consuming a large amount of data from an external API, which has around 150k rows, which contain the large text in some of the fields. I'm able to construct the entities by the data consumed with 5-10Sec of time (max 15-Sec), But saving these entities are taking around 20-30mins. Wanted to speedup this, how we can make it better?

currently using `Repo.saveAll(entities);`

Its a single table and entity, not having any children's

Dev stack:

- MySQL
- Hibernate
- Spring Data JPA
- Java 11

**Observations:**

- When breakpoints are enabled, saving takes more time. Without breakpoint saving time takes around 15-20min, with breakpoint saving time takes around 20-30min
- **Memory and CPU** utilization is normal **40-50%** utilization including other applications running

Comment: If you're auto-generating ids, make sure the generation strategy isn't `GenerationType.IDENTITY`

Comment: @OsamaAbdulRehman, yes am not using any GenerationType.IDENTITY, we are giving the unique id from api and setting that only.

Comment: If you don't need Hibernate to maintain the entities in memory during this processing, then you should skip using JPA entirely and go to the JDBC layer and insert them directly.

Comment: You should also avoid using words that are only used in your part of the world, like "lakh". Others will not understand what you mean.